Spring boot - OAuth 2.0 - Cognito problem. I can´t authorizate using OAuth
I'm trying to build a REST API where the user authenticates using OAuth 2 with AWS Cognito.
No matter how much I try, I can't even get it to launch.
I just only want an easy example of it.
package com.test.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2AuthorizedClientService;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.registration.ClientRegistrationRepository;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2AuthorizedClientManager;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.AuthorizedClientServiceOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http, 
            ClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository, 
            OAuth2AuthorizedClientService authorizedClientService) throws Exception {
        http.csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable())
            .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth
                .requestMatchers("/login").permitAll()
                .requestMatchers("/api/**").authenticated()
                .anyRequest().authenticated())
            .oauth2Login(oauth2 -> oauth2
                .clientRegistrationRepository(clientRegistrationRepository)
                .authorizedClientService(authorizedClientService));

        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public OAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager(ClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository, 
            OAuth2AuthorizedClientService authorizedClientService) {
        return new AuthorizedClientServiceOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager(clientRegistrationRepository, authorizedClientService);
    }
}

This is my application.properties
spring.application.name=test

debug=true

spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.cognito.client-id=dummyAccessKey
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.cognito.client-secret=dummyAccessKey
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.cognito.scope=openid,profile,email
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.cognito.client-name=Cognito
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.my-client.authorization-grant-type=authorization_code
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.cognito.authorization-uri=https://XXXXXXXXXX.com/oauth2/authorize
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.cognito.token-uri=https://XXXXXXXXXX.com/oauth2/token
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.cognito.user-info-uri=https://XXXXXXXXXX/oauth2/userInfo
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.cognito.redirect-uri={baseUrl}/login/oauth2/code/{registrationId}

This is the pom I'm using
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.1</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>
    <groupId>com</groupId>
    <artifactId>test</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>test</name>
    <description>Project for Test</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>

This is the log
2024-12-28T14:35:25.639+01:00  WARN 15548 --- [test] [main] o.s.w.c.s.GenericWebApplicationContext:
Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt:
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration':
Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'httpSecurity': Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.HttpSecurityConfiguration':
Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setContentNegotiationStrategy' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration':
Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setConfigurers' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.OAuth2ClientConfiguration$OAuth2ClientWebMvcSecurityConfiguration':
Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.OAuth2ClientConfiguration$OAuth2ClientWebMvcSecurityConfiguration]: Constructor threw exception

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!
